# "Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context .." with PWA on iOS

Tags: ios, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, web-share

I am currently facing an issue while implementing Web Share API (Level 2) in Vue 3 using it to share/download images on iOS 14 (as experimental feature) and iOS 15 in a Progressive Web App context.

Observation: When the application is running directly in the Browser (not in the PWA Context - which is a local PWA accesible through the homescreen Bookmark on iOS), it also works as expected without any errors.

Installed as a PWA, however, sharing works as expected THE FIRST time, but AFTER saving the image, it refuses to trigger the native sharing mecanism with the error message (note it ALWAYS works once):

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not
> allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context,
> possibly because the user denied permission.

The navigator.share is triggered directly by a click event, the resource is also loaded in advance and sharing.

It seems to work fine on Android Devices as expected but on IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be (again) a regression of an old WebKit bug. In the past, this was repeatedly reported, for example as [WebKit bug #216913](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216913) or [WebKit bug #218156](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218156).

Please [report this to the WebKit team](https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=WebKit), providing the exact iOS and Safari version you encountered this on. Feel free to use this [demo app](https://pear-foggy-breakfast.glitch.me/) that I have prepared, it's an installable PWA and showcases the Web Share API.